# How to use Views contextual filters with a hierarchical taxonomy path in the URL

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

If I have a multi-level taxonomy, and the URL for each Term contains information about its parents in each URL component, how can I set up a View to show the content for each Term?

**Example of the taxonomy:**

- News » UK » Politics » Government
- News » UK » Health

**Example of the matching URLs:**

- mysite.com/news/uk/politics/government
- mysite.com/news/uk/health

I've tried the all the obvious combinations of contextual filters I can think of, but I can only get it to pick up the first part of the URL component (/news) but not the actual term being viewed ('government' or 'health' in these examples).

**System info:** Drupal 7, Views 7.x-3.7, Pathauto 7.x-1.2